# References by chapter and global references

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing

I'm writing my thesis, but I need to get the bibliography for each chapter, and place a global bibliography at the end of the document. I use the 
\usepackage[sectionbib]chapterbib, works well but I can not get the global references

What I need to get is about

1. Name of the Chapter 1                                             1

   1.1 Section 1 ................................................. 2

   1.2 Section 2 ................................................. 3

   References .................................................... 4
2. Name of the Chapter                                               2

   2.1 Section 1 ................................................. 5

   2.2 Section 2 ................................................. 6

   References .................................................... 7

Global References                                                    10

Comment: Were do the global references come from? I mean, from some kind of foreword/epilogue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To cite the documentation of chapterbib:

> 1. To have a cohesive bibliography for the whole document, plus individual
>      bibs in the chapters, put `\bibliography` commands in the included chapters
>      plus in the root file; use `\usepackage[rootbib]{chapterbib}`; run LaTeX;
>      run BibTeX on the root file; change to `\usepackage{chapterbib}`; run
>      LaTeX; run BibTeX on each included file; run LaTeX; run LaTeX.
>      This produces an independent 'overall' bibliography which only makes
>      sense for various 'named' bibliography styles; a style with numbering
>      will give unrelated numbers in each bibliography.
>          Actually, you probably don't *need* to ever run with `[rootbib]`
>      because, although bibTeX should complain about multiple `\bibdata`
>      commands, it should produce all the right bbl files -- but the root
>      `\bibliographystyle` must come first in the document.

Comment: I use the option \usepackage[rootbib,sectionbib]{chapterbib} and works well, thanks. I understand that references will not match